# Unable to remove new line character from String when added to list?

Tags: python

```
test="""SUPREME BASICS
     310 HENDERSON DR"""
#test = test.replace('\n', ' ')
list=[]
list.append(test)

for file_content in zip(list):
    file_content=str(file_content)
    file_content = file_content.replace('\n', ' ')
    print(file_content)
```

Output:

('SUPREME BASICS\n     310 HENDERSON DR',)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two errors:

```
test="""SUPREME BASICS
310 HENDERSON DR""" # Changed this line
#test = test.replace('\n', ' ')
list=[]
list.append(test)

for file_content in list: # Changed this line
    file_content=str(file_content)
    file_content = file_content.replace('\n', ' ')
    print(file_content)
```

Here is an example of why it failed:

```
list=["""SUPREME BASICS
     310 HENDERSON DR""", "asdf\n"]

for file_content in zip(list):
    file_content=str(file_content)
    file_content = file_content.replace('\n', ' ')
    print(file_content)
```

Comment: @eric16384 -

Now it gives output as  `["('SUPREME BASICS\\n         310 HENDERSON DR',)"]`

Comment: Are you manually compressing it onto one line, or is that actually what it is printing?

Comment: My bad! I misunderstood! I will fix it immediately!

Comment: Multiline strings include the indent. Therefore, do not use an indent. Also, do not use ```zip()``` on a single iterable. I also recommend not having your variable be named ```list``` because that is already a built-in class.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my code. Appreciate the quick responses.